# django procfile can't find settings.py

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv, foreman

I'm using heroku and django / vertualenv ... I used this boostrap file: https://github.com/mtigas/heroku-django-demo-app/blob/master/tldr.markdown, named my app `contest2` but when I try to run foreman locally with `foreman start` I get:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
11:10:06 web.1     | ImportError: Could not import settings 'src/contest2/contest2/settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

From the dir the procfile is in, this path: `src/contest2/contest2/settings.py` is correct.

My procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 9 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --preload src/$PYTHON_APP_NAME/$PYTHON_APP_NAME/settings.py > Procfile
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `src/contest2/contest2/settings.py` is fed to the `__import__` function.

You can try to simulate the error:

```
>>> __import__('path/module.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
>>>
```

You probably want to change that to have the python module name and not the path.

The easier way would be to make sure that `src/$PYTHON_APP_NAME/$PYTHON_APP_NAME/` is on your path, and just use `settings` as module name.

You might want to have a look at [the source of the `gunicorn_django`command](https://github.com/tilgovi/gunicorn/blob/py24/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py)  to figure out how this works:

Comment: awesome, thanks.  I added it to my python path and used contest2.settings.py